# Blocking version StringIO.readlines()

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a way to let StringIO.readlines() block until the stream is closed or new data is made available via write()?

I'm writing against an interface that expects blocking file like objects and it immediately returns before I can write data to the StringIO instance. Using the initial_value parameter is also not an option, as I need to use the intermediate results.

Alternatively is there any other (text) file like fifo/stream in python?

Comment: Who writes to the stream? Other thread? If so, you can use [Queue](http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html).

Comment: I write to the stream in one thread, the data is read in an other. I can't use a Queue as the interface expects to get a file like object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use [threads](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#module-threading) then you should use [Queue](http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html). It will save you serious headaches that you would certainly get if you used  some other structure to inter-thread communication.

If you need only `readlines()` and `write()`, then you can wrap `Queue`:

```
class QueueStream(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._queue = Queue()

    def write(self, line):
        self._queue.put(line)

    def readlines(self):
        while True:
            item = self._queue.get()
            yield item
            self._queue.task_done()
```